# Errors with installing netlify CLI

Tags: node.js, npm, netlify

Trying to install Netlify CLI to follow a tutorial about using Notion's API. Ran `sudo npm install netlify-cli -g` in terminal and got an error I'm not sure how to interpret it. I don't have command line tools so that might be why I'm having trouble?? When I went to install it though it was 13gb, so preferably a solution that doesn't require this would be great.

````
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @netlify/esbuild@0.13.6 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @netlify/esbuild@0.13.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```

here's the full error log:
```> yarn@1.22.15 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

/usr/local/bin/netlify -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/bin/run
/usr/local/bin/ntl -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/bin/run

> husky@4.3.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/husky
> node husky install

husky > Setting up git hooks
git --version command failed. Got xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
.
husky > Failed to install

> @netlify/esbuild@0.13.6 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/esbuild
> node install.js

Trying to install "@netlify/esbuild-darwin-64" using npm
Failed to install "@netlify/esbuild-darwin-64" using npm: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/esbuild/esbuild-b1ugyvs5pd'
Trying to download "https://registry.npmjs.org/@netlify/esbuild-darwin-64/-/esbuild-darwin-64-0.13.6.tgz"
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/esbuild/install.js:199
      throw e;
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/esbuild/bin/esbuild__'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1528:35)
    at installBinaryFromPackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/esbuild/install.js:62:6)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/esbuild/bin/esbuild__'
}
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/routing-local-proxy-win32-x64@0.34.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/routing-local-proxy-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/routing-local-proxy-win32-x64@0.34.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/routing-local-proxy-linux-x64@0.34.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/routing-local-proxy-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/routing-local-proxy-linux-x64@0.34.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/routing-local-proxy-darwin-arm64@0.34.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/routing-local-proxy-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/routing-local-proxy-darwin-arm64@0.34.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-win32-ia32@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-win32-ia32@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-win32-x64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-win32-x64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-openbsd-x64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-openbsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-openbsd-x64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"openbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-ppc64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-ppc64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-ppc64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ppc64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-x64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-x64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-ia32@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-ia32@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-arm64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-arm64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-freebsd-x64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-freebsd-x64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-arm@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-linux-arm@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-freebsd-arm64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-freebsd-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-freebsd-arm64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @netlify/local-functions-proxy-darwin-arm64@1.1.1 (node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/local-functions-proxy-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @netlify/local-functions-proxy-darwin-arm64@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @netlify/esbuild@0.13.6 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @netlify/esbuild@0.13.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```
````

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are doing this on macOS and that you are installing a development/administrative tool and this is not your production server. There are a few ways to solve the `EACCES` problem. In my experience, the one that involves the least friction on development machines is to not use a system Node.js but to instead install Node.js per-user using a version manager like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). Then you won't need `sudo` and all the `EACCES` issues basically go away because "global" installations happen in a subdirectory of your home directory.